# JavaScript - Photoshop - How to get machine userName

Tags: javascript, photoshop

My script is running batch processes on .psd files on a server so I am not able to get the user from the .psd filePath. I need to return the machine username so  I can add it to the time-stamped log entry I am using to record each process.

I tried running:

```
#target photoshop  

var usersFolder = Folder("C:\\Users")
var users = usersFolder.getFiles()
alert(users.join("\n"))
```

...to find the current user folder, but it returned it as **~** (tilde).
Is there a way to retrieve the current username from the **~** path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following gist:

```js
#target photoshop

/**
 * Ascertains whether the Operating System is Macintosh.
 * @returns {Boolean} True if the OS is Macintosh, otherwise false.
 */
function isMacOS() {
  return ($.os.toLowerCase().indexOf('mac') >= 0);
}

/**
 * Obtains the computers name/username.
 * @returns {String} The name of the computers username.
 */
function getUserName() {
  return (isMacOS()) ? $.getenv("USER") : $.getenv("USERNAME");
}

var userName = getUserName();

alert(userName);
```

---

**Notes**

1. The `getUserName` function returns the computer/user name by running either:

   - `$.getenv("USER")` if the operating system is Macintosh.
   - `$.getenv("USERNAME")` if the operating system is Windows.
2. I haven't tested this running on Windows, as I don't have a copy of  PhotoShop running in that environment.
3. However, `$.getenv("USERNAME")` does work successfully in InDesign running on Windows.
4. If this fails on Windows then I suggest you try changing the `$.getenv("USERNAME")` part to one of the following instead *(and infer the value if necessary)*:

   - `$.getenv("COMPUTERNAME")`
   - `$.getenv("USERPROFILE")`
   - `$.getenv("HOMEPATH")`